# How to get a specific kernel sources?

Tags: kernel, development, software-sources

I'd like to get the kernel sources related to my installed image. Currently I have the version 3.19.0-39 installed into my VM.

When trying to get the sources, I searched into cache using `apt-cache search linux-source` and got info for 3.13.0 - Linux kernel source for version 3.13.0 with Ubuntu patches.

How can I get the sources related to 3.19.0-39?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get it using "apt-get build-dep + "..